# How to repeat and split this vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, run-length-encoding

I have *one* index vector with nine elements,`IDX = [1 2 1 3 4 3 1 2 1]`.(in another post, I asked about how to repeat two separate vectors IDX1 and IDX2, but here I have all the elements in one vector)

The first five elements of this matrix are to be repeated according to elements in `howMany1 = [3 2 2 1 2]`, the next four elements are to be repeated according to `howMany2 = [2 1 2 2]`. So the result would be: `a1 =[1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 4 4]` and `a2 = [3 3 1 2 2 1 1 ]`. 
How could I do it by MATLAB such that the result is stored in two separate matrices in a cell?
Here is my code, but I can not find out what the problem is. Thank you all for taking the time.

```
clear all
close all
clc

IDX = [1 2 1 3 4 3 1 2 1];
howMany1 = [3 2 2 1 2]; % howMany1 and howMany2 determine how many times each index in IDX should be repeated.
howMany2 = [2 1 2 2];

%%
howMany = {howMany1 howMany2};
a = cell(2,1)
m = 1
for k = 1:2
 for j=m:length(howMany)+m-1
     h = howMany{k};
     idx=IDX(j);
     a{k,1}= cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) repmat(x,1,y),idx,h(j),'uniform',0))
 end
 m = m+length(h)
end
```

Comment: No Daniel, its not repeated, my problem here is totally different from what  I asked before. Thank you

Comment: It is apparently not clear what the difference is between the two. I can't see the differences other than some variable names. If you do not think this is a duplicate, please modify your question.

Comment: Here I have all indexes together in a matrix. I don't have them separated as the previous question. This is where Im stuck: I don't know how to split IDX .

Comment: I just know that IDX is to be separated according to the length of howMany1 and howMany2.

Comment: I still believe this is a duplicate even with after your comment. You may edit the question, link to the other question and explain **thoroughly**, and in a way that makes it obvious to other people what the difference is, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Split IDX using `idx1 = IDX(1:numel(howMany1))` and `idx2 = IDX(numel(howMany1)+1:end)` and look up the colon operator in the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tomas! The problem is solved, great! You made my day! Wish you a nice day! :)